# How do I pass a variable through Stripe checkout to my success page?

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I am going to use Stripe checkout (as I'm not a strong coder) to have my users pay for their subscriptions. Once they go through this process I want to update my DB to flag their "paid" column in the DB so they can be active.

The issue that I'm having is passing their Member ID from their admin page through the checkout page (as it's on Stripe's servers) then back to my success page.

Here is the code I'm using to for the checkout:

create-checkout-session.php

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
// This is your test secret API key.
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('###');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://www.website.com';

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'line_items' => [[
    # Provide the exact Price ID (e.g. pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
    'price' => 'price_1LYCH2Ks11D5pGt5Dd6Yda8g',
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'subscription',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.php',
  /* 'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.php?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}', */
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
  'automatic_tax' => [
    'enabled' => true,
  ],
]);

header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);

?>
```

And it get's called just with a simple button

```
          echo "<script src=\"https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch\"></script>
                <script src=\"https://js.stripe.com/v3/\"></script>
                  <form action=\"http://www.website.com/create-checkout-session.php\" method=\"POST\">
                  <button type=\"submit\" id=\"checkout-button\">Renew</button>
                </form>"    ;

        }
```

Comment: Please remove your API key `sk_test_XXXX`. Even in test mode, malicious actors can be jerks.

Comment: @RyanM ok it's been edited

Comment: Great, I just don't want someone's experience ruined by internet thuggery

Comment: @RyanM Just to add to what Kevin has said, I would actually revoke that API key and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions

> The issue that I'm having is passing their Member ID from their admin page through the checkout page (as it's on Stripe's servers) then back to my success page.

Stripe doesn't have Member IDs but since you are saying it is on Stripe servers I am assuming you are referencing the Customer ID.  If you are referring to some ID from your system you should pass it in the `metadata` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) on the Checkout session.

### Getting Checkout Data

There are a couple methods you can use but it will require some additional coding.

1. Use the Checkout Session ID - You have the default recommended `success_url` in your code.  You can retrieve this from the request query parameters in your PHP code that handles the `/success.php` page.  Then you [retrieve the Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) in your PHP code that runs when a browser hits `/success.php` - Most direct, less ideal results
2. Use webhooks - This requires significantly more code but is a much more robust solution.  It is thoroughly documented for Checkout [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) and Stripe has multiple docs on how to design webhook receivers.  You can start [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

Comment: sorry I didn't mean stripes customer ID. I meant the ID from my site. Basically I'm using this to renew users accounts but I need to pass through their unique ID so I can update the DB. So it's not part of the session and tbh I can't even get that session id working either

Comment: I see you mentioned the metadata which I tried but I couldn't get that working. Do you have an example success page that is using it?

Comment: This page shows you how to retrieve the checkout session from your success url (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page).  In that case you would just extract the `metadata` property from the `$session` object to get your ID.